# Uncaught ReferenceError:ajax is not defined (repeated 2 times)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this form that I must process with Ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="column1">

    <form class="form box" action="javascript:networkCheck();" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <h2>Fly!!</h2>
        <table width="100%" id="fp_network_choice">
            <tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;">Choose Network</td>
            <td style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="network" id="vatsim" value="vatsim"> VATSIM</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="network" id="ivao" value="ivao"> IVAO</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>

        <div class="info" style="display:none" id="loading">Verifying status and flight plan, please wait...</div>
        <div class="info" style="display:none" id="error">Goal</div>
        <br><tr><td><input onclick="networkCheck()" id="check" type="submit" value="Check"></td></tr>
    </form>

</div>

<script>


        function networkCheck(){

            var vatsim = 1;
            var icao = 0;

            ajax.open("POST","network_check.php",true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4)
                {
                document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';

                }
            }
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("vatsim="+vatsim+"&ivao="+ivao);

        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
        }
</script>
</head>
```

I'm getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError:ajax is not defined (repeated 2 times). I see the error with chrome debugger.

I don't know why? Maybe JQuery version???

Comment: Just like it states, the `ajax` variable is not defined. At the top of the function do `var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ajax.open("POST","network_check.php",true);` but haven't defined `ajax` or loaded a library that will have done it for you.

You are missing `var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();`

That said, since you are using jQuery, you'd probably be better off using its [helper functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).